# opencv install on ubuntu error about cv2

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I'm on ubuntu 14.04 I'm trying to install openCv but I'm getting an error

```
Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (32-bit)| (default, Jun  2 2014, 12:37:33) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/laptop1/anaconda/bin/../lib/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/sse2/libx264.so.142)
>>>
```

I've install libc6 following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421642/libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found) but I'm still getting an error.

I've install openCv following this [tutorial](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Fk_TDtEYP2b3LLZQTsYia96HplF_5mV7wHlRgcwBHVk/pub) but this didn't work so I've tryied it with `conda install opencv`but I get the same answer

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this link
https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!msg/anaconda/R0RdG3HQONg/j1VEElh1IWUJ
it says that it could be solved by

```
conda update cairo
```

And the reason of such error may due to the incompatible version of different modules.

I had the same problem and the above command worked for me.